# I want to get the list of ids of users I select in recyclerview in order to add them to group chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a chat app similar to that of whatsapp and in the part where user creates a group, i want to add all users i select from the list, in other words, and return their ids so they can stored together in firebase in order that messages sent in that particular group will reach every user in the group. But am lost on how to go about that. Below is the code in my recyclerView:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterAddUsers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterAddUsers.ViewHolder> {

    Admin admin;

    // variable to store admin uid from sharePreference
    //String admin_uid;

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Users> mUsers;
    private boolean isChat;

    // string variable to contain lastMessage from user
    private String theLastMessage;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterAddUsers(Context mCtx, List<Users> mUsers, boolean isChat){
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.mUsers = mUsers;
        this.isChat = isChat;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_add_users,parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // gets the positions of the all users
        final Users users = mUsers.get(position);

        // sets username to the text of the textView
        holder.username.setText(users.getUsername());

        if(users.getImageUrl() == null){
            // loads the default placeholder into ImageView if ImageUrl is null
            holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_unknown);
        }
        else{
            // loads users image into the ImageView
            Glide.with(mCtx).load(users.getImageUrl()).into(holder.profile_pic);
        }


        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checks if check box is checked
                if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "User is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        Admin admin;

        CircleImageView profile_pic;
        TextView username;
        TextView last_msg;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        // status online or offline indicators
        CircleImageView status_online;
        CircleImageView status_offline;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profile_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_user);
            status_online = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_online);
            status_offline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_offline);
            last_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_msg);
        }
    }

    // checks for last message
    private void lastMessage(final String user_id, final TextView last_msg){

        theLastMessage = "default";

        // getting the uid of the admin stored in shared preference
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        final String admin_uid = preferences.getString("uid","");

        DatabaseReference lastMsgRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        lastMsgRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Chats chats = snapshot.getValue(Chats.class);

                    assert chats != null;

                    // compares the uid of the admin and user and return the last message
                    if(chats.getReceiver().equals(admin_uid) && chats.getSender().equals(user_id)
                            || chats.getReceiver().equals(user_id) && chats.getSender().equals(admin_uid)){
                        theLastMessage = chats.getMessage();
                    }

                }

                // switch case for theLastMessage
                switch (theLastMessage){
                    case "default":
                        last_msg.setText(R.string.no_message);
                        break;

                        default:
                            last_msg.setText(theLastMessage);
                            break;
                }

                theLastMessage = "default";
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // display error message if one should occur
                Toast.makeText(mCtx, databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: If you consider at some point to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: ooh nice.. i will check that out...Thanks man...

Answer (score 0):

I put an arrow (like this <----) where you have to make changes to your code

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapterAddUsers extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterAddUsers.ViewHolder> {

Admin admin;

// variable to store admin uid from sharePreference
//String admin_uid;

private Context mCtx;
private List<Users> mUsers;
private boolean isChat;

// string variable to contain lastMessage from user
private String theLastMessage;

// strings to store the ids of chat users <--------------------------------------------
private List<String> selectedUsersIds;
//getter method
List<String> getUserIdsList(){
    return selectedUsersIds;
}

public RecyclerViewAdapterAddUsers(Context mCtx, List<Users> mUsers, boolean isChat){
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.mUsers = mUsers;
    this.isChat = isChat;
    selectedUsersIds = new ArrayList<String>(); // <--------------------------------------------
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_add_users,parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // gets the positions of the all users
    final Users users = mUsers.get(position);

    // sets username to the text of the textView
    holder.username.setText(users.getUsername());

    if(users.getImageUrl() == null){
        // loads the default placeholder into ImageView if ImageUrl is null
        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_person_unknown);
    }
    else{
        // loads users image into the ImageView
        Glide.with(mCtx).load(users.getImageUrl()).into(holder.profile_pic);
    }


    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // checks if check box is checked
            if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(mCtx, "User is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //add the user id to the list <--------------------------------------------
                selectedUsersIds.add(users.getId()); // or whatever the method to get the user id name have <--------------------------------------------
            }
            else{
                //remove the id if the user it's unchecked <--------------------------------------------
                selectedUsersIds.remove(users.getId()); // <--------------------------------------------
            }
        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUsers.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    Admin admin;

    CircleImageView profile_pic;
    TextView username;
    TextView last_msg;
    CheckBox checkBox;

    // status online or offline indicators
    CircleImageView status_online;
    CircleImageView status_offline;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        profile_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_user);
        status_online = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_online);
        status_offline = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status_offline);
        last_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_msg);
    }
}

// checks for last message
private void lastMessage(final String user_id, final TextView last_msg){

    theLastMessage = "default";

    // getting the uid of the admin stored in shared preference
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
    final String admin_uid = preferences.getString("uid","");

    DatabaseReference lastMsgRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    lastMsgRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Chats chats = snapshot.getValue(Chats.class);

                assert chats != null;

                // compares the uid of the admin and user and return the last message
                if(chats.getReceiver().equals(admin_uid) && chats.getSender().equals(user_id)
                        || chats.getReceiver().equals(user_id) && chats.getSender().equals(admin_uid)){
                    theLastMessage = chats.getMessage();
                }

            }

            // switch case for theLastMessage
            switch (theLastMessage){
                case "default":
                    last_msg.setText(R.string.no_message);
                    break;

                    default:
                        last_msg.setText(theLastMessage);
                        break;
            }

            theLastMessage = "default";
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // display error message if one should occur
            Toast.makeText(mCtx, databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

then, in the class where you instantiate the adapter call the get method for the userIds list, something like this.

```
List<String> userIds = adapter.getUserIdsList();
```

That way you can do whatever you want with that list of selected userIds

Comment: But please where from the getUserIdsList()? Is that a getter method for the selectedUsersIds?

Comment: @alisampson    yes, that's the getter method, you should call it in the event triggered when you want to start the chat

Comment: @alisampson i updated my answer, i forgot to add the method

Comment: Thank you @karique

Comment: But am finding it difficult to access it because of the type..For instance, in the groupChat activity i have create a List<String> usersids that is suppose to return the list of ids of users of a particular but getting it from the model class returns and error "Can't convert type to Java.util.list"

Comment: Also whenever i get the list of ids , they get printed together with their positions in the list.How do i get rid of the position numbers please ?